# Angular 4 reusing one component in another

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Hi All I am using Angular 4 for my current project. I'll try to explain my problem scenario before diving into the question.
I have created several components inside the "app" folder, and created "Feature Module" inside each component. So one of these component is named "focus". 
[image: Focus Component]
Now I have a requirement where I need to display the content of the component "focus" 
inside another component "iu".

Before moving on I would also like to add that in both of these components there are sub-components depicting step 1 - 7 as
per my requirement. [image: iu component]
Now in "iu" component's step3 by clicking on an icon I want to open a modal window and display the content of "focus" component (step 1 - 7).

This is what I have written in step 3 of "iu" for displaying "focus" screens:

```
    <div class="model fade" *ngIf="showAppCaptureData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewAppCaptureData" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewAppCaptureData">AppCapture Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="showAppCaptureData=false">
          <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <app-proposal-form></app-proposal-form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the Feature module of my "focus" component I am exporting the parent element which contains step 1 to 7.

And in the Feature module of "iu" component I am importing that elt and using the corrosponding selector in step 3 of "iu" component 
and defining the corresponding routes.

You can see the same in the image which I have attached.

this is the code I have written for displaying focus component content in step 3 of iu component:

**The issue is that when I click on the icon which changes showAppCaptureData to true, instead of displaying the content in a modal window it displays the content 
in the same  space.**

As shown in the below image:
[image: Before Click]
[image: After Click]

I am thinking that the issue is because of  in my iu-form.component.html file.

I understand it might not be easy to understand the full scenario only by this much description and little code. Please do let me know if I need to post any other code which I have written for this.

Please advice how can I overcome this issue and display the content in modal window.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use an existing public library for your modals?

Comment: yes, I am using bootstrap 4 modal

Comment: So you included ng-bootstrap in your project, but I don't see you using the bootstrap modal directive. Instead you copy/pasted the DOM code and added an `*ngIf` clause. If you don't use the component, no css styles will be applied (See ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: Nico am afraid I didn't fully understand the point you have mentioned above. I'll check "ViewEncapsulation" though and just wanted to mention that I used the code mentioned here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/